# Cannot Connect to Docker Daemon - Windows 10 WSL

Tags: docker, tcp, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu Bash is windows 10. I have been struggling with connecting to the Docker Daemon. There has been couple of queries in the past which I followed with not luck.

From the search I could see that the TCP endpoint need to be open for connection to the Docker Daemon. Followed the following excellent posts with no luck:

https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/
https://blog.bigfont.ca/run-docker-from-the-wsl/

The content of the above blogs are of few months back. May be process has changed for today.
Please guide.

Comment: What version of Docker do you have installed on Windows 10? Also, why not run Docker directly on Windows, what's the requirement here?

Comment: $ sudo docker version

Client:

 Version:       18.04.0-ce

 API version:   1.37

 Go version:    go1.9.4

 Git commit:    3d479c0

 Built: Tue Apr 10 18:20:32 2018

 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

 Experimental:  false

 Orchestrator:  swarm

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: I am currently working on an Ubuntu based project

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command from your WSL command line :

```
echo "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `wsl-2 , hypervyser issues` try following hacks

**1) Open services from windows start menu**

[image: Services]

**2. Click on Startup type and `select Automatic`**

[image]

**Note:**

If you are getting the issue of *" Access denied "* while selecting Startup type as Automatic then open your PowerShell and type the following command:

(Make sure you have admin access for PowerShell)

```
 Set-Service LxssManager -StartupType "Automatic"
```

Done, Now open your docker desktop app

[image]